# Loop through System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary via for statement

Tags: c#, generics, loops

I have a quick question. Is there way to easy loop through `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` via `for` statement in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you looking for a specific Value or KeyValue pair?

Comment: I assume you mean foreach rather than for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in a reasonable way, no. You *could* use the Linq extension `ElementAt`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value);                
}
```

...but I really don't see the point. Just use the regular `foreach` approach. If you for some reason need to keep track of an index while iterating, you can do that "on the side":

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] - {1}", index, item.Value));

    // increment the index
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use foreach:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

// ...

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kv in dictionary) 
{
    string key = kv.Key;
    string value = kv.Value;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it has been fixed in the meantime

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways.
Looping through the keys:

```
foreach(var key in myDictionary.Keys)
```

looping through values:

```
foreach(var value in myDic.Values)
```

looping through pairs:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<K, V> p in myDic)
{  
     var key = p.Key;
     var value = p.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `for` is mostly for collections with indices.
You can `foreach` over it easily, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Net 3.5 or later then you can use LINQ and a predecate to locate a specific Value or Values.
Dictionaries do not necessarily store their KeyValue pairs in order (either by entry order nor Key order).

Answer (score 0):

Philippe's got it for `foreach`, though I usually simplify it to:

```
foreach (var pair in dictionary) 
{
    var key = pair.Key;
    var value = pair.Value;
}
```

There's no way to loop through this collection of key-value pairs using a `for` loop because they aren't stored in order. You can loop through the keys or the values as collections though.

Comment: Using "var" is terribly bad practice in general.

Comment: @Nyerguds that's an awfully sweeping and objective statement. It's also incorrect - the `var` keyword is absolutely essential in any circumstances where you're using anonymous types. Also, in this case the asker didn't specify the generic types on the dictionary and I find (in the real world) that sometimes you need to change the types. My use of `var` makes the exact type of the dictionary irrelevant and is code that works regardless of the generic types. There's lots of places I wouldn't let a `var` through a code-review, but in an example snippet it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It can ofc be done, but it is a bit silly IMO

```
        Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator enumerator = dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributeValues.Count;i++ )
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> current = enumerator.Current;
            //do something usefull
            enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
```

the only thing gained by this is a (fairly useless) index, and if that is the actual goal, you are better served by something like this:

```
        int currentIndex = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            //do something usefull
            currentIndex++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be a "for"-loop, maybe using the [Dictionary.GetEnumerator Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c6ftx8b(v=vs.85).aspx)  with a "while"-loop is an option - it is pretty easy as well *IMHO*:

```
var enumerator = d.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
var pair = enumerator.Current;
b += pair.Value;
}
enumerator.Dispose();
```

code-snippet from [C# Dictionary GetEnumerator](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-getenumerator)

Comment: Why would you do this over using a `foreach`?  Also, you're not disposing of the enumeartor.

Comment: the code-snippet is from http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-getenumerator, it is not my code. And according to that website, using the enumerator has a better performance than 'foreach' - which is why i think it is worth mentioning the enumerator

Comment: It doesn't matter if its your code or not.  It's not good code, and you should either fix it, or not use it.  It's important to dispose of the enumerator; if you want to enumerate explicitly, you need to do that.  As for it being better than a `foreach`, it's exactly what a `foreach` is going to do.  `foreach` is just syntactic sugar for this (except that `foreach` does it correctly, unlike your code).  A `foreach` will be no slower; it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop over the keys

```
 for(int i = 0; i < myDictionary.Keys.Length; ++i)
      myDictionary.Keys[i] ...
```

or the values

```
 for(int i = 0; i < myDictionary.Values.Length; ++i)
      myDictionary.Values[i] ...
```

Or both as Philippe shows

Comment: That will not compile `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>KeyCollection'`

Comment: He was looking for: Count instead of Length, which only applies to 'normal' arrays

Comment: @Oxymoron: even when using `Count`, trying to access elements in the `Keys` collection by index (`Keys[i]`) will still break the build (which was the error I was referring to in my comment).